# Vue.js Events: How to detect if key is pressed while the mouse is over a certain element?

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, mouseevent, vue-events

I am currently working on a multi item selection component in Vue.js 3.

Each item is represented by a `<div>` element containing a checkbox.

**For a feature I want to implement I need to detect when the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed while the mouse is over a `<div>`.** (My goal is to have all the items between the item checked last and the item currently under the mouse highlighted while the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed, and then have them all checked with <kbd>Shift + Click</kbd> - but that is beside the point).

I tried to achieve this using `@mouseover.shift` like so:

```
    <div v-for="item in items"
         class="item"
         @mouseover.shift="onMouseOverShift(item)"
    >
```

Unfortunately, while `@mouseover.shift` works fine to detect whether <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed **when the mouse enters the `<div>`**, but does not trigger when the key is pressed **while the mouse is already inside of the `<div>`**.

Do you know what would be the best way to achieve what i am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use like this:

```
<div v-for="item in items"
    class="item"
    @mouseenter="isMouseOver = true"
    @mouseleave="isMouseOver = false"
    @keypress.shift="onMouseOverShift(item)"
/>
```

Then on the method **onMouseOverShift** you check if **isMouseOver**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can detect a keypress on a div, or at least not reliably. You best bet is probably to combine the mouse events with a global key watcher.

In Vue 3 composition API, this would look something like this:

In your component setup:

```
const hoveredItem = ref(null)
const shiftPressed = useShiftKeyWatcher()
const selectedItem = computed(() => shiftPressed.value ? hoveredItem.value : null)
```

In the template:

```
    <div v-for="item in items"
         class="item"
         @mouseenter="selectedItem = item"
         @mouseleave="selectedItem = null"
    >...</div>
```

Then the [composable](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) for useShiftKeyWatcher would look like:

```
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from "vue";

export function useShiftKeyWatcher() {
  const shiftPressed = ref(false);

  function checkKeyDown(event) {
    shiftPressed.value = event.key === "Shift";
  }

  function checkKeyUp(event) {
    shiftPressed.value &&= event.key !== "Shift";
  }

  onMounted(() => window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyDown));
  onMounted(() => window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp));
  onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener("keydown", checkKeyDown));
  onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp));

  return shiftPressed;
}
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-microservice-j3qqw7?file=/src/components/Panel.vue) (you need to click into the preview area once to have key events go to the inner document)